# Lim Inf and Lim Sup of Double Sequences

Tags: limits, analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Given a double sequence $(a_{n,m})_{n,m \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $0 \leq a_{n,m} \leq C$ for some constant $C > 0$, and knowing that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_{n,m} = 0$ for any fixed $m$, does it follow that
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \left( \limsup_{m \to \infty} a_{n,m} \right) = 0?
$$
I am looking for a proof or counterexample of this statement.

Comment: Counterexample: We can define $a_{n,m}=1$ if $n\leq m$ and $0$ otherwise. Then your expression is $1,$ not $0.$